# An unhandled exception occurred while processing the request InvalidOperationException: The views was not found

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, razor-pages

I get this error when I press my "edit" and "delete" buttons. In short, I am in the process of developing a website where administrators can see their created users and make changes.

```
<td><a asp-controller="Admin" class="btn btn-sm btn-primary" asp-action="Edit" asp-route-id="@item.record_id">Edit</a></td>
<td><a asp-controller="Admin" class="btn btn-sm btn-danger" asp-action="Delete" asp-route-id="@item.record_id">Delete</a></td>
```

The error message I am getting after the button is pressed:

```
An unhandled exception occurred while processing the request.
InvalidOperationException: The view 'Edit' was not found. The following locations were searched:

/Views/Admin/Edit.cshtml
/Views/Shared/Edit.cshtml
/Pages/Shared/Edit.cshtml

Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ViewEngines.ViewEngineResult.EnsureSuccessful(IEnumerable<string> originalLocations)
```

This error occurs for both buttons and gives exactly the same error. I have read that this error is because there are multiple locations for the file. But there isn't and I don't understand that. What is the cause of my error?

Here's an image of my project strucutre:
[image]

Comment: Do you have views for "Edit" and "Delete"?  Where in the project are those views?

Comment: The views are placed inside Pages, and my AdminController is inside the Controller folder. I have updated the main thread with image.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> The view 'Edit' was not found. The following locations were searched:
>
> /Views/Admin/Edit.cshtml
> /Views/Shared/Edit.cshtml
> /Pages/Shared/Edit.cshtml

The error means that the framework could not find a view file (.cshtml file) named `Edit` in any of the locations listed. These are the default locations for view templates in ASP.NET Core MVC. The first is in a folder in the *Views* directory named after the controller, and the other two are general locations where you would typically place view files that might be used by more than one controller action (such as a Layout file).

The view file itself should be named after the controller's action method (i.e. *Edit* or *Delete* in your case). Rename the Pages folder to Views and put your view files in an Admin folder within that:

```
> Views
    > Admin
        Edit.cshtml
        Delete.cshtml
```

Answer (score 1):

The error doesn't mean "multiple locations were found", but means "this file cannot be found at correct location". 
For a MVC project structure, you should place the `.cshtml` file in a folder structure like `root/{ControllerName}/{ActionName}.cshtml`
For example

```
    public class AdminController : Controller
    {
        [HttpGet]
        public async Task<IActionResult> Index()
        {
        }
        [HttpGet]
        public async Task<IActionResult> Details(int? id)
        {
        }
        [HttpGet]
        public IActionResult Create()
        {
        }
        [HttpGet]
        public async Task<IActionResult> Edit(int? id)
        {
        }
        [HttpPost]
        public async Task<IActionResult> Edit(int id, [Bind("Id,Name")] Student student)
        {
        }
        [HttpGet]
        public async Task<IActionResult> Delete(int? id)
        {
        }
```

The .cshtml should be placed like
[image: ![enter image description her]
The `Pages` folder is usually for Razor pages project structure. This structure doesn't need controller because every page has a .cshtml.cs with it to process the request.
[image]